# Finding Time bug in Swift 3.0

Tags: swift3

After converting my code to Swift 3.0, I have just one error left, saying that 'dateComponents' produces 'DateComponents', not the expected conextual result type 'NSDate?' I'll add a * on the line that error applies to. The * is not in the actual code.
I did not understand the code before hand, as it was written by a person I am no longer in touch with. The code sets a starting date for a timetabling app I wrote.

My code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var llllll: UILabel!
class CyclicDay {
    enum CyclicDayError: Error {
        case invalidStartDate }
    lazy var baseline: NSDate? = {
        var components = DateComponents()
        components.day = 2
        components.month = 5
        components.year = 2016
       * return NSCalendar.current.dateComponents(components) }()
    func dayOfCycle(_ testDate: NSDate) throws -> Int {
        if let start = baseline {
            let interval = testDate.timeIntervalSince(start as Date)
            let days = interval / (60 * 60 * 24)
            return Int(days.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 14)) + 1 }
        throw CyclicDayError.invalidStartDate }}
```

Comment: Date returned an error in every instance, until I read that Swift 3 required NSDate. Sure enough, no more errors.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info! It now reads: return Calendar.current.dateComponents(components) }()        However, the new error is: 'dateComponents' produces 'DateComponents', not the expected contextual result type 'Date?'

Comment: Thanks a bunch rob, want to post as an aswer so I can credit you with it?

Comment: By the way, I know you were just trying to get this code to compile, but it's a little dangerous. What if the user wasn't using a Gregorian calendar? The date you're going to get will be very different than the date you intended. I might suggest using `Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)` rather than `Calendar.current` if you're going to hard code Feb 5, 2016. You may want to make a mental note to review the code for general compatibility with non-Gregorian calendars. I'd be surprised if this was the only place the original developer made this assumption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of issues:

1. In Swift 3, you should use `Calendar` and `Date` rather than `NSCalendar` and `NSDate`.
2. The method to get the `Date` object from a `DateComponents` is [`date(from:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/calendar/2292916-date). The `dateComponents` method is for going the other direction, to determine the `DateComponents` from a `Date`.

Thus:

```
lazy var baseline: Date? = {
    var components = DateComponents()
    components.day = 2
    components.month = 5
    components.year = 2016
    return Calendar.current.date(from: components)
}()
```

Or

```
lazy var baseline: Date = {
    var components = DateComponents()
    components.day = 2
    components.month = 5
    components.year = 2016
    return Calendar.current.date(from: components)!
}()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Calendar and Date rather than NSCalendar or NSDate. It may solve the problem. Most of 'NS' prefix are abondoned in swift 3.0

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why is `baseline` optional? The date 2016/5/2 doubtless exists.

The Swift 3 equivalent is simply

```
lazy var baseline: Date = {
    let components = DateComponents(year:2016, month:5, day:2)
    return Calendar.current.date(from:components)!
}()
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, as stated in the question, this is the only section of the code I did not write. I simply continued another person's code, from 2016.

Comment: `date(from: components` can return an optional date because the components could be out of range (for example `day:32`), but there is not reason at all to use an optional date in this case., the optional can safely be unwrapped. Btw: Using `86400` as constant for date math is very bad programming habit.